# Find the version of Newlib component

Tags: linux, puppeteer, version, chromium, newlib

How to find the version of **Newlib** component.

Path at

/app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-1036745/chrome-linux/nacl_x86_64.nexe